# IdentityServer3 - post request for access token with hybrid flow?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, hybridauth, openid-connect

This is quite simple task but as I am also quite new to OIDC and security, it puzzles me.

I have instance of IdentityServer3 and the client created on the server. It utilizes hybrid flow. I know it's something between implicit and auth code flow, so I assumed I could use authorization_code or implicit grant type, but obviously not. How is possible to get access token through postman please?

My current request:

- client_id:sch
- client_secret:testKey
- grant_type:authorization_code
- scope:openid profile offline_access email

My current response:
{

```
"error": "invalid_scope"
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified **AllowedScopes** for your client ?

```cs
AllowedScopes = new List<string>
{
    "openid", "profile", "otherScopes"
}
```

or you can just allow all scopes for now

```cs
AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
```

To get access token from Postman, you need to setup client for postman first, use AuthorizationCode Flow for it

```cs
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Postman",
    ClientId = "postman",
    Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCode,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 43200,
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
    },
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
    RequireConsent = false
}
```

Now to grab token in Postmant

- Go to Authorization tab
- Choose type OAuth 2.0
- Click **Get New Access Token** Button
- Fill out those fields
- Click Request Token

Auth URL: https://yourIdenityServerAddress/identity/connect/authorize

Token URL: https://yourIdenityServerAddress/identity/connect/token

[image]